# Symbolic Representaion of Links and Joints: How to sketch complex manipulators using simple symbols?

Tags: manipulator

In some papers and books we can see that authors using symbols to represent robot arms. My question is, is there a convention for such sketches? If so could you provide a reference which shows how these symbols should be used?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are usually only two kinds of joints you would use in a robot - a revolute (rotational) joint and a prismatic (translational) joint. Every reference I've seen uses a cylinder to represent revolute joints and a cube or prism to represent a prismatic joint.

You might be able to argue that a cylinder should represent a cylindrical joint, but in reality a cylindrical joint is a combination revolute and prismatic joint.

There are spherical (ball) joints, but I have never seen an actuated spherical joint before. They're more used as a kinematic constraint in shoulder joints or suspension design, in which cases the joint is a *pivot* and the *actuation* is still done by prismatic joints.

Comment: "Usually only two kinds of joints" - I guess I should say two kinds of *actuated* joints.

Comment: Yes, however, the from a schematic point of view, active or passive joints are not graphically distingushed (the just have a "$q_i$" written next to them sometimes)